# Shifting Vowels at the end of the Singly Linklist

Tags: c++, linked-list

The following is the code I have written to solve the particular problem. But I am having problems with solving two edge cases. The case where the first element itself is a vowel, and the case where the last element is the vowel. Now as for the first edge case, I think it can be solved by iterating through the list till we find a vowel, and inserting the head node before the said node, and update the head pointer. But in the 2nd case, the case where the last element is a vowel, in that case, my code is running into an infinite loop. How can I handle that particular case? Also, if you can suggest any different approach towards solving the problem, please do so and if you can, please suggest any kind of improvement I can apply in the code.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    char ch;
    node *next;
};

void enqueue (node **head, node **tail, char val)
{
    node *newn = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newn->ch = val;
    newn->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = newn;
        *tail = newn;
    }

    (*tail)->next = newn;
    (*tail) = newn;

}

void print (node *head)
{
    while (head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<head->ch<<" ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

bool isVowel (char ch)
{
    ch = ch | 32;

    if (ch == 'a' || ch =='e' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u')
        return true;
    return false;

}



node* segregateVowels (node *head, node *tail)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return head;

    node *temp = head;
    node *fin = tail;

    while (temp!=fin)
    {
        cout<<temp->ch<<" "<<fin->ch<<endl;
        getchar();
        if (isVowel(temp->next->ch))
        {
            node *shift = temp->next;
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
            tail->next = shift;
            shift->next = NULL;
            tail = shift;
        }
        else
            temp = temp->next;

    }
    return head;

}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;

    int i = 20;

    while (i>=0)
    {
        enqueue (&head, &tail, rand()%26+65);
        i--;
    }

    print(head);


    head = segregateVowels (head, tail);


    print(head);
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing a linked list instead of using `std::list` or `std::vector` or `std::deque`?

Comment: I am not very well versed with STL library. I usually code in C and have just recently made a transition to C++. Plus I find it kind of convenient to write my own helper functions also it gives me a practice over the common data structures.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the second edge case where the last element is a vowel:
replace

```
while (temp!=fin)
```

with

```
while (temp->next!=fin)
```

The fact is you need not check the data of `fin`. If it is a vowel, then its already segregated to the end. If its consonant it also satisfies the conditions. Either way it doesn't effect the result. Of course, you need to handle some other cases when the size is 1.

Handling first edge case is simple.

Write a small if condition which checks for the vowel in the head node and update the pointer correspondingly before the start of the `while` loop. You are done!

I have another simple approach:
Assuming it is doubly linked list...

Take two pointers `head`(pointing to starting of the list) and `tail` (pointing to the end of the list). Now try understanding the following code:

```
int head_count=1, tail_count=linked_list_size;
while(head_count<tail_count)
{
     while(!isvowel(head->data) && head_count<=linked_list_size)
     {
         head=head->next;
         head_count++;
     }
     while(isvowel(tail->data) && tail_count>0)
     {
          tail=tail->prev;
          tail_count--;
      }
     if(tail_count>head_count)
     {//swap the values..
          char tmpc = head->data;
          head->data = tail->data;
          tail->data = head->data;
     } 
 }
```

Time Complexity:`O(N)`
Space Complexity:`O(1)`

Another approach which uses an extra space of `O(N)`...

- Create two arrays.. `vowels` and `consonants` array.
- Parse the linked list until the end and store all the letters into their respective arrays.
- Now overwrite the data in the linked list first with the letters in `vowels` array and then with consonants array.

Time Complexity: `O(N)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That solved the bug. Don't know why I didn't think of this. 
Your suggestion is based on the partition method of the Quick Sort I believe. And it's a valid solution. But I was looking for a stable algorithm. One that would not change the order of the vowels and the consonants. 
On the lines of your second approach, instead of building an array, we can create two lists itself, and traverse our original link list, deleting characters one by one and inserting in the appropriate LinkList and then we can join the two lists. That would give us O(1) space complexity.

Comment: I was just trying to keep things simple. You can also use two LLs instead of arrays. But then, that is nearly same as your earlier method. But anyways, its fine.. :) :)